# Exponent value not displaying,what should i do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

how to display exponent value after calulation to textbox in iphone sdk.For example say 6.4516e-10.i am not getting answer for it in my textbox after calculating 10 * 6.4516e-10.please tell me solution..

Comment: plz help me out of this problem,it's urgent.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use StringWithFormat and exponent formations:

From the man page on printf:

eE  The argument is printed in the style e `[-d.ddd+-dd]' where  is one digit before the decimal point and the number after is equal to the precision specification for the argument; when the precision is missing, 6 digits are produced.

So you would want a format something like: %.4e

```
float n =  6.4516e-10;
n = n * 10;
NSLog(@"n: %.4e", n);
```

2011-08-29 07:36:38.158 Test[39477:707] n: 6.4516e-09

Comment: :---Thanks for the reply,but the value 6.4516e-10 is not constant in my app.It may be any other value.point is that my answer in exponent format is not displaying as i run application and click calculate buuton.Actually i have created 1 textbox which takes input from user and 2 dropdown list which includes from and to conversion units.on calculate buuton click i want to display answer in another textbox.another simple values are calcuated with no problem in it but if the answer is in exponent form it not giving me proper ans.it is giving me 0